# How to run aws scheduler-cli in a Python script?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to run scheduler-cli of AWS Instance Scheduler from my Python script. I tried to do it via boto3, but may be its not supported there. As I am able to run scheduler-cli via windows command prompt, so trying to use subprocess to run scheduler-cli from a python script but getting error. Following is code snippet and the error:

```
                cmd='scheduler-cli create-period --name "testperiod" --begintime 07:00 --endtime 20:00 --weekdays mon-fri --stack instance-scheduler --description "7 AM to 8 PM Monday to Friday" --region ap-southeast-2'
                try:
                subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    print("Could not create period.")
```

The error I am getting is following:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'scheduler-cli create-period --name "testperiod" --begintime 07:00 --endtime 20:00 --weekdays mon-fri --stack instance-scheduler --description "7 AM to 8 PM Monday to Friday" --region ap-southeast-2' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The command works fine from windows shell. May be I need to give aws credentials somehow in the script, but as I am iterating through different accounts so need to give different sts credentials but not sure how to set those for subprocess.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of the caught exception? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by running the scheduler-cli command from the os package as API from AWS isn't available for yet.

```
           cmdschedule='scheduler-cli create-schedule --name testschedule --periods testperiod --timezone Australia/Sydney --stack teststack --description "6 AM to 8 PM Monday to Sunday" --region ap-southeast-2'
            try:
                myCmdperiod = os.popen(cmdperiod).read()
```